# Multiple $("selectort").click (function () in if then construction not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a server that dynamically(asp.net ) generate webpages that I can't alter.

On all pages I would like to capture all buttons clicked.

In JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/forssux/aub2t6gn/2/ is an example..

```
$(".checkout-basket").click (function ()
```

The first alert shows the 3 possible values,
but not the chosen item..

```
$(".button.button-dl").click(function ()
```

In jsfiddle this part doesn't get executed

Strangely on my real webpage I get the button clicked...but when I put it in the If then construction it fails to console.log the chosen item..
I hope somebody can explain me how to get these..

Kind Regards
Guy Forssman

```
 //$("div.detail-info,table.checkout-basket").click(function () {
 //       var knopje = $(this).attr("class")//.split(" ");
 //     console.log(knopje + " knopje was clicked");
 //       if(knopje.indexOf("detail-info") > -1) {
 //          console.log("div class detail-info is clicked");
 //     }
 //     else if (knopje.indexOf("checkout-basket") > -1) {
 //           console.log("table class checkout-basket is clicked");
 //            }
 //       else {
 //       alert ("er is op iets anderes gedrukt");
 //       }

    // capture click on download button in checkout-basket page
    $(".checkout-basket").click (function () {
    basket =[];
    item="";
        str = $(this).text();
        str = str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        var str = str.match(/("[^"]+"|[^"\s]+)/g);
        console.log("Array  ",str);
        for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(str[i] === "verwijder"){
           console.log("Item= ",str[i+1]);
           item = str[i+1];
          basket.push(item);}
        }
        console.log("Basket contains ",basket);
        //console.log("idValBasket ",idVal);
        var test = idVal.replace(/\$/gi, "_").slice(0,-6);
        console.log("test ",test);
        var element = test.substr(test.length - 2)-1;
        console.log("element ",element);
        element=element-1;
        item = basket[element];
        console.log("Item finaal is ",item);
        });

    $(".button.button-dl").click(function () {
        var addressValue = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log("addresValue Basket",addressValue );
        var re = /'(.*?)'/;
        var m = addressValue.match(re);
        console.log (" m basket is ",m);
        if (m != null)
        idVal = (m[0].replace(re, '$1'));
        console.log("idVal Basket",idVal);
      });

    //This section captures the download in the detail page

    $(".button").click(function () {
        var downloadItem = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML 
        console.log("addresValue detail",downloadItem );
      });
```

Comment: *"it fails"* .. how?

Comment: I altered the question a bit....console.log("Item finaal is ",item); doesn't show up ...

Answer (score 0):

I never use click function, `use on(*event*,...)` instead:

```
$(".checkout-basket").on("click", function (){ /* CODE */ });
```

Check if visually there are a layout over the a layuot (a div, span, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a strange question and maybe i got it wrong, but why do you use push ?? if you want to delete an item ? btw also the example isn't working so maybe that is your problem